# Javascript - How can I get perfect window object from another server?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I execute this javascript code,

```
var youtube = window.open("https://www.youtube.com", "_blank");
console.log(youtube.document);
```

the printed "document" object has no contents. Is there another way to get youtube's window object?

Comment: That's a cross-origin frame and you're not allowed to manipulate things like this. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Nope. Think about it, if you can manipulate other window objects you can essentially hack into other websites.

Comment: All the accounts in the world would be hack if that was possible